# Configure subdomain at AWS Route 53

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a domain hosted at AWS Route 53 (running on a EC2 instance) for a about a year now. Let's say its domain is domain.com. My Hosted Zone looked like:

```
domain.com.              NS   <dns records>
domain.com.              SOA  <value>
```

Now, I developed another app and I want it to run at a subdomain. So, I went to my existing Hosted Zone and added a CNAME record as follows:

```
Name: subdomain 
Value: <ip for the domain>
```

So, now my Hosted Zone has 3 records:

```
domain.com.              NS   <dns records>
domain.com.              SOA  <value>
subdomain.domain.com.    <ip address for domain>
```

At my EC2 instance, my Apache file looked like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    SetEnv production
    <Directory /var/www/domain/>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I added the following for my subdomain to work, right below the previous VirtualHost section:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    SetEnv production
    <Directory /var/www/subdomain>
      Options -MultiViews
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when I type subdomain.domain.com in a browser, I get `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

**UPDATE:**

I apologyze if I'm changing the subject of the original question a little, but I've now decided to go for joyastressa.com.ar. Last night I registered the domain, created a new Hosted Zone in Route 53 and added the four DNS that are shown on that screen to the newly created domain. It's been almost half day since then and when I ping joyastressa.com.ar I get nothing. What could be wrong?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Try an A record rather than CNAME.

Comment: If the value is an IP address then the record type needs to be `A` instead of `CNAME`.

Comment: Record A with Alias or without it?

Comment: I replaced it with an A record but it's still not working...any ideas?

Comment: Does your new route53 record have a health check enabled? Can you browse directly to your IP address?

Comment: @BrianRoisentul just an A record, with Alias set to "no."  If it's still not working, you'll probably need to give us your domain name before we can make any helpful observations.

Comment: @Michael The A record is not working with Alias set to "no" either. The subdomain is joyas.tressa.com.ar. The domain tressa.com.ar works just fine but the recently created subdomain doesn't.

Comment: @systemjack I've enabled a health check and it says "unhealthy"

Answer (score 0):

Is the original domain hosted in Route53? Definitely looks to be issue with DNS. The SOA record for your new domain doesn't look like an AWS generated one. Which means that the Route53 setting can't take effect since non-AWS organization has authority over the domain.

Check out [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html). Might help.

```
dig tressa.com.ar

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tressa.com.ar.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tressa.com.ar.          3528    IN      A       54.174.201.212


dig joyas.tressa.com.ar

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;joyas.tressa.com.ar.           IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tressa.com.ar.          455     IN      SOA     pdns05.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. 2016050200 28800 7200 604800 600
```

Comment: The linked page is one solution but if OP is under the impression that the root domain is hosted in Route 53 (which -- I agree with your conclusion -- it is not), we don't want that resource to be a distraction, when the simpler fix is to change the authoritative nameservers with the registrar.

Comment: Hi, when I developed the app I asked the client to add the AWS Route 53 DNS. I didn't register the domain. Anyway, now we have decided to register another domain for this app. Thanks anyway.